# How do I use an id_token issued by Google as a JWT Bearer Grant

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I want to use the id_token issued by Google OAuth2/OIDC provider as a JWT Bearer grant[1] at some other Identity Provider(say X) to obtain an access_token.

Everything is fine except for 'aud' claim of the id_token. According to the JWT bearer spec[1], the 'aud' claim should contain some identifier of IDP X (tokenEndpoint Alias is the commonly used value). AFAIK the only claim that we have in the id_token at the moment is the client_id of OAuth2.

Is there a standard way to configure some identifier of X to be included in the id_token so that it becomes a valid jwt bearer grant to be used at X?

I think this problem is not specific to id_tokens coming from Google but rather for any OIDC provider.

[1] https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer-12#section-3

Comment: The JWT used by the JWT Bearer grant type is not the `id_token` (which represents the resource owner that granted the client), but requires a token issued by the client itself or a trusted issuer.

Comment: Is there a specification or standard endpoint from which a client can ask for a JWT bearer grant from an IDP?